# Appropriate leading for blogs?

Tags: formatting, blog, conventions

Is there a [leading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading) (i.e., *line spacing*) commonly considered appropriate for most types of blogs? I'm referring, specifically, to "regular" blog posts, i.e. not asides, snippets, galleries, etc.¹

For my purposes, you could define this as a minimum of 500 words.

Please note that I'm not talking about a "standard" leading (although if, by some miracle, it exists, please do tell), but merely one that is *commonly agreed upon* or, at the **very** least, commonly *used*. (Basically, I'll take whatever you can give me; I just want to get *as close as possible* to a standard as one can observe in blog writing.)

---

¹ On WordPress.com, these would be labeled *Text* posts, the others often being *Photo*, *Video*, *Quote*, *Link*, *Aside*, *Gallery*, *Status*, *Audio*, and *Chat* posts. ([See here.](https://en.support.wordpress.com/posts/post-formats/))

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about writing but about web usability.

Comment: It is **not** about web usability. It is about *writing conventions*.

Comment: I was asking about whether there is a leading that is commonly expected for blogging. >:( How the heck does that have **anything** to do with web usability. It's **only** about socially determined style guides.

Comment: If this were a question about print typsetting I don't think we would close it as off-topic.  Why is the web different?

Comment: The visual appearance of a published text is not part of the writing of it (at least not usually in prose). That is why manuscripts are usually *unstyled* and all look the same. The published text is then designed, by choosing a specific font, a font size, a font color, a background color, etc. And wether or not this text is readable and pleasant is the topic of web usability. It is not part of writing. In a usual publishing process, it is not done by the writer. Only in self-publishing does the writer also design the text, but that does not make designing part of writing.

Comment: @MonicaCellio StackExchange has sites for web design and web usability, and similar questions are often asked there. Which doesn't actually make it off topic here, but a better fit there. People there are probably more knowledgeable as well.

Comment: This sounds like a typesetting question, which should be off-topic here.

Comment: I'm not at all sure typesetting issues are off-topic here. We're focused on writing, but we also handle questions to do with publishing, production, and the like. There may be other SE sites where this is appropriate, but I think it's on-topic here.

Comment: @Standback: THANK you. Plus, oftentimes, the formatting of text is *directly* related to how it is interpreted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although with respect to the post by "what", I must disagree that leading is defined by the user. Most users have very little knowledge of adjusting their browsers anything beyond default.

This leaves the decision of leading to the blog writer, who may or may not be skilled in CSS to be able to alter it.

As such, standard typography conventions for leading usually default to 120% of the point size of the type. Thus a 10 point font usually gets 12 point leading. However, the most finely typeset documents, are ones that have been manually leaded and kerned (another discussion). Meaning, depending on the specific font, the leading is adjusted manually for optimum reading.

Also a consideration from the print world, is the length of the line of text. In print, a line of text should average 9 - 15 words, much like how the lines are being displayed here.Lines with much longer text will require more leading, whereas shorter lines will require reduced leading.

Summary: dependent on font. Investigate CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The "appropriate" leading on websites is that defined by the user agent.

Unfortunately a large number of web designers appear to be unaware of the fact that users use a wide variety of operating systems, screen sizes and web browsers. The best usability experience is that provided by user agent standard settings.

Unless you are very sure what you do (and how to do it correctly), do not change font size, line height and other font metrics on a website.

Comment: I didn't mean font metrics on the *website*; I was referring only to font metrics for stuff I type. I mean, like, **literally the text I type** on, say, WordPress or whatever for blog *posts*. Not the website, just the text in the text post I make. This question is about writing, not web design.

Comment: A blog is a website. The text you publish appears online. No one cares how you set up the backend to display the text to you while you compose it, but once you *post* the post, that is, once you publish it to the web, it is on a website (your blog) and how that looks is determined not by your writing but by the design of your website/blog.

Comment: Well I didn't know that. Now I do. Thank you for telling me that. I learned something new today.